# CloudFront Invalidation doesn't work

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, invalidation

I have the following image in an S3 bucket.

```
/images/thumbnails/654-thumb2.jpg
```

In my C# code, I've created an invalidation for that specific path. The validation runs as I verified it via the console and I see the following object path in the invalidation detailes:

```
/images/thumbnails/654-thumb2.jpg
```

After the invalidation finished ("Completed" state), I go to check if the image was updated, but it remains the same as before. I've double checked that this is the right CloudFront distribution and it is. I also checked that there isn't a typo and the path is written ok.

When I open the file in S3, I see the new image, but it is not being updated on the CDN after invalidation.

Any idea what I need to do to make it work?

I'm developing in C#/ASP.NET 4.5

Comment: Can you capture the response headers from CloudFront and S3 `GET` requests for the object and add them into the question?  Have you verified the behavior with `curl` and elminated the browser cache or any transparent intermediate caches?

Comment: Man, I was stuck on this one. Turned out to be Cloudflare getting in the middle and providing its own caching. Cloudfront was invalidating just fine. Doh...

Answer (score -1):

Either you've missed something, or you've uncovered a bug!
Double check your origin and behavious to make sure you're pointing at the S3 path you think you are, then raise it with AWS support.

Comment: It's a pretty safe assertion that this is not going to be a bug. Perhaps you meant that as satire.  This answer would be better if you would explain some details, such as how to verify whether CloudFront is serving a specific response from the cache by examining the reaponse headers, and what "double check" means, in detail.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to comment but I wasn't able to since I'm new here. Not entirely satire, we find issues occasionally and raise them with Amazon, maybe not bugs but intermittent failure. The only other thing I can think of is that you've said you've invalidate an S3 path, while invalidations work with CloudFront paths (often the same thing, but not always)